# "Eine schrecklich nette Familie": why?

Tags: adjective, adverb

Why isn't it

> Eine schreckliche nette Familie

? I suspect it has to do with the adjective/adverb dualism, but even then I can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `schrecklich` in this sentence is describing the `nette`. So yes, you were right, the adjective/adverb dualism is the cause.

The `schrecklich` here indicates that they're awfully nice, or maybe even shockingly nice. It would be a lot more clear if we had more context.

> Eine schreckliche, nette Familie

This sentence, note the comma, would mean that the family is both `schrecklich` and `nett`.

Comment: For the context: [Eine schrecklich nette Familie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eine_schrecklich_nette_Familie) is the German title of the TV sitcom [Married… with Children](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Married..._with_Children)